# Most computationally efficient way to count the number of instances of each unique value in a pandas column?

Tags: pandas

From a pandas column, I would like the count of how many times each unique column value appears in that column.

Currently I am using this

`count_dictionary = df.column_name.value_counts()`

But for tens of millions of rows, it is taking many hours to process.

Is there a more computably efficient way to calculate this dictionary?

Comment: I think numoy here should be faster, pass `df.column_name` instead 1d array like `np.bincount(df.column_name)`

Comment: numpy right? I think there's a typo

Comment: Yes, sure `numpy`